# Git commit from an ADO PR pipeline to source branch not working

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Background:
The Operations team makes changes to an xlsx file to update azure resource cofiguration. As xlsx changes are not visible in ADO, and to catch errors early in the code cycle, we are developing a PR pipeline. The pipeline should also be work when ran manually from a branch.

Goal:
To have a yaml pipeline run when a change is made to xlsx file and a PR is created. This will checkout the source branch, run a pwsh script to ingest the xlsx and generate the files, then add the modified/new bicep templates back to the PR.

pipeline steps:

```
pr-pipeline.yml:
...
# checkout (works)
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Git checkout branch
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/LoNaLo
    # $branch param to use $(Build.Reason) condition to check if branch is a pullrequest, and use $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch) if true or $(Build.SourceBranch) if false - will enable pr to be ran manually.
    script: |
      Write-Host "Reason: $(Build.Reason)"
      if ('$(Build.Reason)' -eq 'PullRequest') { $branch = '$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)' }
      else { $branch = '$(Build.SourceBranch)' }
      Write-Host "Branch: $branch"
      git config --global user.email "pipeline@proximus.com"
      git config --global user.name "pipeline"
      git checkout -b $("$branch".replace('refs/heads/', ''))

# Script execution (works)
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    azureSubscription: '${{parameters.azureResourceManagerConnection}}'
    scriptType: 'FilePath'
    scriptPath: ${{parameters.pwshFile}}
    azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
    errorActionPreference: 'stop'
    scriptArguments: -xlsxConfigFile "${{ parameters.xlsxConfigFile }}" -outfileDirectory "${{ parameters.outfileDirectory }}"
###### this part does not work ######
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Git commit changes
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/LoNaLo
    script: |
      if ('$(Build.Reason)' -eq 'PullRequest') { $branch = '$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)' }
      else { $branch = '$(Build.SourceBranch)' }
      Write-Host "Branch: $branch"      
      Write-Host "**checkout master**"
      git checkout master
      git pull origin master
      git checkout $("$branch".replace('refs/heads/', ''))
      git merge main
      Write-Host "**status**"
      git status
      Write-Host "**add**"
      git add .
      Write-Host "**commit**"
      git commit -a -m "Update Branch $branch with generated templates" --allow-empty
      # Write-Host "**Branch**"
      # git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$("$branch".replace('refs/heads/', ''))
      Write-Host "**pull $branch**"
      git pull origin $branch
      Write-Host "**push**"
      git push --set-upstream origin $("$branch".replace('refs/heads/', ''))
```

This is the current itteration, which is a little messy!

If ran manually, the pipeline completes and shows the files

The DevOps output error when running this version (the Git Commmit task produces this):

```
Branch: refs/heads/test/bm/pr-fix
**checkout master**
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
From https://dev.azure.com/quest1/LoNaLo/_git/LoNaLo
branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
[new branch]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
Already on 'test/bm/pr-fix'
M   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumaemacc.bicep
M   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumaemauthoracc.bicep
M   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumaemauthortst.bicep
M   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumaemtst.bicep
M   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumotheracc.bicep
M   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumothertst.bicep
M   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumtst.bicep
merge: main - not something we can merge
**status**
On branch test/bm/pr-fix
Changes not staged for commit:
>  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
Changes not staged for commit:
   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumaemacc.bicep
modified:   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumaemauthoracc.bicep
modified:   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumaemauthortst.bicep
modified:   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumaemtst.bicep
modified:   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumotheracc.bicep
modified:   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumothertst.bicep
modified:   030-Security/frontdoorwaf/afdv2/templates/wafafdpremiumtst.bicep

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
**add**
**commit**
[test/bm/pr-fix 6b23f06] Update Branch refs/heads/test/bm/pr-fix with generated templates
7 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
**pull refs/heads/test/bm/pr-fix**
From https://dev.azure.com/quest1/LoNaLo/_git/LoNaLo
branch            test/bm/pr-fix -> FETCH_HEAD
[new branch]      test/bm/pr-fix -> origin/test/bm/pr-fix
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
**push**
To https://dev.azure.com/quest1/LoNaLo/_git/LoNaLo
[rejected]        test/bm/pr-fix -> test/bm/pr-fix (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/quest1/LoNaLo/_git/LoNaLo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

We have tried various git commands mentioned in other questions here, including this which seemed to be a close match (and matched a similar error we had initially): [Git/ Azure Devops Pipeline Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74309965/git-azure-devops-pipeline-issues)

And this one gave hints on the branch: [Azure Devops Build Pipeline from PR Trigger get source branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687544/azure-devops-build-pipeline-from-pr-trigger-get-source-branch)

and we found useful information on the 'hidden' branch created in ADO, when actioning a PR: [Why in Azure DevOps build pipeline refers to a different commit during the pull request checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832596/why-in-azure-devops-build-pipeline-refers-to-a-different-commit-during-the-pull)

I'm pretty sure it related to the source branch that the commit is targeting/adding to, but I seem to be going around in circles.